# How to call javascript function from handlebars js template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

On button click, I have to change the CSS width :

```
 {{#if this.text}} 
     <div id = {{this.id}} class="sidepanel">
        <button  class="closebtn" onclick="{{close(this)}}">×</button>
        <h1> {{this.text}}</h1>
     </div> 
   <button  onclick="{{open(this)}}" class="openbtn">Open</button> 
 {{/if}}
```

inside script file I have two functions:

```
  function close(data) {
     document.getElementById(data.id).style.width = "0px"
   }

  function open(data) {
    document.getElementById(data.id).style.width = "100%"
  }
```

**Problem:** I am not sure how to call these functions from the handlebar template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` and `close` are not available to the Handlebars context, so we definitely don't want to be invoking them from within handlebars expressions `{{ }}`.

The part about these invocations that is known to Handlebars is the `id`, so the simplest thing to do would be to render the `id` so that it will be passed to the function when the button it is attached to is clicked.

Note: I am going to rename these functions from `open` and `close` to `openSidepanel` and `closeSidepanel` because `open` is an [existing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) on the `window`.

Our function definitions becomes:

```
function closeSidepanel(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = "0px"
}

function openSidepanel(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = "100%"
}
```

and our template becomes:

```
<div id = {{this.id}} class="sidepanel">
  <button  class="closebtn" onclick="closeSidepanel('{{this.id}}')">×</button>
  <h1> {{this.text}}</h1>
</div> 
<button  onclick="openSidepanel('{{this.id}}')" class="openbtn">Open</button>
```

Notice that we wrap quotes around what is rendered for our `id` so that it will be treated as a JavaScript string.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vtysmp51/3/) for your reference.